Looking for the title of an old science fiction book about a man sent to a crystal planet
Both my father and I read this book and are looking for the title. It's about a future where a man working for a corporation is tasked with checking out a crystal planet. He travels there alone, wears a special metal suit that protects him, and finds the research base destroyed. Everything is made of crystals (dangerous fauna and flora), his suit is damaged by the local wildlife and he is injured. Then some alien creatures repair and modify him- for example, he wakes up and his eyes can now filter the harsh light reflected from the crystal plants. He meets the aliens/ crystal beings and realises they are sentient and intelligent. He later meets a woman from the research base, she has also been modified by the aliens, and together they try to protect the planet from the new team the corporation sent. The book is wonderfully descriptive and I think it was written in the 1970/80s. It's written from the man's perspective and he's a bit arrogant at the beginning but changes as the book progresses.

Likely a dupe of Book: Mechsuit on a crystal planet is destroyed by native vegetation

Sentenced to Prism by Alan Dean Foster.

From the Wikipedia plot summary:

Set in the Humanx Commonwealth, Prism is a unique planet because its ecosystem contains both silicon-based and carbon-based life. Evan Orgell, a management troubleshooter sent to Prism to investigate the disappearance of a research group, finds himself fighting for his survival in this strange crystalline environment after his specialized environment suit succumbs to the local elements. Leaving behind his mechanized suit, Evan is for the first time in his life exposed to a hostile environment without the protection of his suit and must rely on the unexpected help of the native sentient life to survive.


If accepted, duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/235562/28516
